# Pandas: Fast way to fill a dataframe based on a function on the index and column name of each element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a function `foo` which takes two auguments `str_a` and `str_b`.

First I creat a dataframe with the same index and columns from a list `list_of_strs`, so

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = list_of_strs, columns = list_of_strs)
```

Now, I want to fill the dataframe with each element equal to the output of the `foo` function using the corresponding index and column name of this element: `foo(index, colnumn)`.

I can think of using two `for` loops as follows:

```
for str_a in list_of_strs:
    for str_b in list_of_strs:
        df.loc[str_a,str_b] = foo(str_a,str_b)
```

How can I do it more efficiently and why it is faster than the for loop?